# Is all life north of the wall now dead?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of season 7-the dead are officially marching into Westeros. It may be time for their march-but is it correct to say that all life north of the wall is dead? Or is it just all humans are dead? Or are there still survivors somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately this is opinion-based as we don't know. There could definitely be some people who survived, not everyone has to have died and been turned. The likely answer is humans who haven't died yet, but considering the White Walkers bring the winter with them, they'll probably die in the trailing blizzard

Comment: Castle Black is still manned and intact, and they could certainly send someone under the Wall through their gate, who would then be a human alive north of the Wall.

Comment: @MikeScott That would then mean all life beyond the Wall **was** dead so the question is still fine in that regards.

Comment: What do you consider the White Walkers to be? They are turned as living babies....

Comment: @Skooba Apparently they are alive, I just edited this into my answer :)

Comment: I like to think that Craster’s wives are holding it together, somehow.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Would be quite good if the WWs left them alone due to, at least some of them, being their sons.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: they might be the key to sorting all this out actually. The Night King be all “Bow before me lowly humans, or feel the bitter edge of my frozen bl—” then one of Craster’s wives is like “Kevin! Stop this nonsense at once!” and the Night King’s all “*Muuuuuuum*, you’re *embarassing* me.”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## We Don't Know

It would seem that all life we know of north of the Wall is dead:

- Wildlings: Most probably died at Hardhome.
- Children of the Forest: Died during the attack on the Three-eyed Raven's lair.
- Benjen Stark: Was already dead but was re-killed in the merry men's attempt to capture a wight.
- Craster's lot: Presumably all dead.

However, the North is a large place and we don't know exactly how many White Walkers there are that can turn the dead. So it would appear to us, the viewer, that all are dead. However, it is also very possible that some people have managed to survive and evade the White Walkers. The north is a large place.

Also remember that the White Walker's, although have been taking their time, seem to have made their moment to attack the 7 kingdoms. When the time is now you don't wait to pick up a few surviving stragglers you go for it with all your might.

As @Flater mentions in a comment it also seems likely that animals can still be alive beyond the Wall:

- We see a bear wight, presumably it was living beyond the wall before it was killed.
- The Three-eyed Raven's ravens can live north of the Wall.
- Animals that wildlings used to eat had to live beyond the Wall, same goes for whatever Craster and his lot ate.

It would make sense, as we don't see too many wight animals, that some of these are still alive.

White Walker's seem to be another species and are alive in their own right. As per the Season 7 finale we only saw a couple cross the Wall. Even though we don't know the exact amount we know there are at least more than that so it makes sense to state that not everything is dead beyond the Wall... at the moment.

Comment: I think the OP asked about animals too (I'm basing this off of the OP saying _"Or is it just all humans are dead?"_). Animals are at least _capable_ of surviving beyond the Wall (cfr Bran's flock of ravens). Assuming that the bear wight used to live beyond the wall too (pre-wight), I would say that it's likely that animals still live beyond the Wall.

Comment: @Flater Yeah likely, though I'd put that in the same bucket as people evading them and it being a large place.